# Eclipse Activity Not Working

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to hide elements in the UI by means of activities like this

```xml
<plugin>

   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.startup">
      <startup
            class="StartUp">
      </startup>
   </extension>  

   <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.activities">  
<activity id="com.lowcoupling.actitivities.unwantedActionSet1" name="Unwanted Search ActionSet">  </activity>
<activityPatternBinding
      activityId="com.lowcoupling.actitivities.unwantedActionSet1"
      isEqualityPattern="true"
      pattern="org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.discovery.ui.menu.toolbars.discoveryCommand">
</activityPatternBinding>
 </extension>

</plugin>
```

but when I run this plugin as another EClipse application the button is still there.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pattern` value for `activityPatternBinding` takes the format:

```
contributing plug-in id / local id
```

so you have to work out which plug-in contributes the menu item. Looking at the Eclipse Papyrus download the plug-in appears to be `org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.discovery.ui.menu` so the pattern is probably:

```
  pattern="org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.discovery.ui.menu/org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.discovery.ui.menu.toolbars.discoveryCommand">
```

(assuming isEqualityPattern="true", all the `.` characters need escaping for the regular expression version)